# char arrays in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char

I'm having a little problem modifying an array in C. I have two arrays, c1 and c2.

I want to manually fill the array `c2` by typing the words array `c1` contains. The user types a letter and if this letter is found in c1, the program fixes this letter in the appropriate place in c2. If the letter doesn't belong to c1, it does nothing. It's just like a "guess the word" game. Here is a sketch:

```
c1 = MARRON

c2: ******
Type a letter: E


c2: ******
Type a letter: A


c2: *A****
Type a letter: O


c2: *A**O*
Type a letter: P


c2:*A**O*
Type a letter: M


c2: MA**O*
Type a letter: N


c2: MA**ON
Type a letter: R

c2: MARRON

You win.
```

My code doesn't really following the sketch above. My problem is printing the asterisks and the letters at the right time. I also found out that the program replaces the last character `'\0'` with an asterisk even though i kept a condition to prevent that.
Here' my code:

```
void complete( char *c2, char c1[], int letter ) {
    int i = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < strlen( c1 ) - 1; i++ )
        if( c1[ i ] == '\0' ) {
            c2[ i ] = '\0';
        }
        else if( letter != c1[ i ] && c2[ i ] != '*' );



        else if ( letter == c1[ i ] ) {
            c2[ i ] = letter;
            c2[ i + 1 ] = '\0';  
        }
        else if (letter != word[ i ] )
            c2[ i ] = '*';
    c2[ i + 1 ] = '\0'; 
}

int main(){
    char c1[] = "ORANGE";
    int length = strlen(c1);

    char *c2 = NULL;
    c2 = malloc(length * (sizeof(c1));

    while( 1 ){
        printf( "What is the secret word?:  ");
        printf( "%s\n", c2 );
        printf( "Propose a letter:  ");
        letter = lirecaracter();//it just reads a character

        char *suite = NULL; 
        suite = strchr(c1, letter );
        if( suite != NULL ){
            complete( c2, c1, letter );
        }

        if( strcmp( c1, c2 ) == 0 ){
            printf( "\n You won, congrats\n" );
            exit( 0 );
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this homework? You need to tag as such if so

Comment: Your first loop is strange you are using else if before an if? Also strlen actually returns the correct length of the string no need for -1

Comment: @andreas: no it's not a homework

Comment: @Peter R.: Oops changed the code. I tried strlen -1 but i still have the same problem.

Comment: Please do something about the terrible formatting of your code if you want people to help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
  WordGuessGame(target[1..n], buffer[1..n], input[1..m])
   1. for i := 1 to n do
   2.    buffer[i] := '*'
   3. print buffer
   4. for i := 1 to m do
   5.    for j = 1 to n do
   6.       if target[j] = input[i] then
   7.          buffer[j] := input[i]
   8.    if buffer = target then
   9.       print "You win!"
  10.       return
  11.    else print buffer
  12. print "You lose..."
```

Answer (score 0):

a solution for your homework is very simple like:

```
int main(){
    char *p,c,*c1 = "ORANGE", c2[]="******";

    while( puts(c2),strcmp(c1,c2) )
    {
      printf( "Propose a letter:  ");
      c=getchar(); while( getchar()!='\n' );
      p=c1;
      while( *p )
        if( *p++==c ) c2[p-c1-1]=c;
    }

    printf( "\n You won, congrats\n" );
    return 0;
}
```